# How to join all Oracle tables in new table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an oracle DB with a lot of tables (more than 60).

For Example:

Table 1

```
  ID        STRING        DATA
   1          ABC         READ
   2          CDE         WRITE
   3          FGH         READ
   4          HSS         WRITE
   5          FFH         WRITE
```

Table 2

```
  ID     Name        Feb  
  1      Deven       12 
  4      Monish      21 
  5      Ritesh      22
```

Table 3

```
ID        STRING         DATA          READY
1          ABC           READ          OK
2          CDE           WRITE         NO
3          FGH           READ          OK
```

I need to create a new table where for each ID It shows all the fields and informations contained in all the db tables for that ID.  All in the same row.:

**NEW TABLE I NEED TO CREATE**

```
  ID        STRING       DATA      Name       Feb       READY
   1          ABC        READ      Deven      12        OK
   2          CDE        WRITE                          NO
   3          FGH        READ                           OK
   4          HSS        WRITE     Monish     21
   5          FFH        WRITE     Ritesh     22
```

Which comand Have I to use?

Please be patient because I’m a newbe of sql language.

Thank you very much

Comment: You want to create a new table containing all of the data from all your other 60+ tables? Why?

Comment: Because I need to export it to excel; and so each ID need to have all the data present in the database (of that ID) insert in the same row

Comment: Thanks for reply :)

Sorry but Isn't there a simple code that find in all the database all the information related to an ID ????

thank you

Comment: "*Sorry but Isn't there a simple code that find in all the database all the information related to an ID*" - no there isn't

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want a big `left outer join` starting with the first table (based on your sample data):

```
select t1.id, t1.string, t1.data, t2.name, t2.feb, t3.ready
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     table3 t3
     on t1.id = t3.id;
```

It is impossible to tell from your sample data if the `id` is the only (or right) `join` key.  However, you should (and need to) know the relationships between the tables in order to create the correct query.

If you want this in a table, just pre-pend the `create table as` statement before the `select`.

Comment: Thanks, But Is there a way to avoid to write all fields name??? (the tables are more than 60, and each table has about 20 differents field)

Answer (score 0):

[Create a view](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_8004.htm#sthref6008) which has the fields that you want. Then execute [`INSERT INTO ... SELECT * FROM view ...`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9014.htm#i2145081).

Comment: Why create a view first? Not sure how this will help the OP really if they are new to SQL. (And why tag with PL/SQL)?

Comment: OK; But Is there a way to avoid to write all fields name and table name??? I see that I have a lot of view already pre-loaded as you can see from the image; But no one has all the field and the table I requrie. Is there a way to simply merge all these view in only one???   image: http://www.webalice.it/boss823/dgflo-1.jpg